# Consolidate list items, based on a reference tree using Python

Tags: python, list, tree

I have a 'reference tree' of hierarchical data. A representative example:

```
1
├── 1.1
│   ├── 1.1.1
│   └── 1.1.2
├── 1.2
└── 1.3
2
├── 2.1
│   └── 2.1.1
├── 2.2
├── 2.3
└── 2.4
3
├── 3.1
└── 3.2
```

I then have a list of items, which are present in my reference tree.

Where *all* children in a subtree are present, they can be consolidated into the node.
I therefore want to simplify lists.

e.g. given input `[3.1, 3.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2]`, I want to return `[3, 1, 2.1, 2.2]` (though the order of the output is not important).

My data set is relatively small, so performance is not an issue. But I'd love to learn how to do this in a beautifully Pythonic way!

I am not sure which techniques, algorithms or data structures may be most appropriate, and am also not sure how to name my problem. So I'm keen to learn more ("*What you're describing is a...*")

Comment: "Closed. This question needs details or clarity." < could I be provided with more details and clarity on what is missing from my question please? It seems Ajax1234 was able to quickly provide an answer...? I would like to improve it, but don't know how.

Comment: It is most likely that those who voted to close the question felt that your post was perhaps too off-topic or broad. It would definitely help if you were to provide a sample of the code you have already written so far and/or a description of what approaches you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursively traverse the structure, choosing the levels and values where all the children at every level exist in your input:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = {'1': {'1.1': {'1.1.1': None, '1.1.2': None}, '1.2': None, '1.3': None}, '2': {'2.1': {'2.1.1': None}, '2.2': None, '2.3': None, '2.4': None}, '3': {'3.1': None, '3.2': None}}
vals = ['3.1', '3.2', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '2.1', '2.2'] 
def get_paths(d, c = None):
   if all(i in vals for i in d):
      yield (c, list(d))
   else:
      for a, b in d.items():
         if b is not None:
            yield from get_paths(b, a)

r = list(get_paths(data))
result = [a for a, _ in r]+[i for i in vals if all(i not in j for _, j in r)]
```

Output:

```
['1', '3', '2.1', '2.2']
```